# How to reverse a cursor in djangoappengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I'm developing and application that requires to paginate a list of links. I'm using django non-rel with djangoappengine.

I'm aware of the functions set_cursor and get_cursor found in djangoappengine.db.utils which make it easy to navigate forward as such:

```
paginate_by = 25
queryset = Link.objects.all()

cursor = request.GET.get('cursor') #Alternatively passed via ajax in a POST request
if cursor:
    queryset = set_cursor(queryset, cursor)

links = queryset[0:paginate_by]
next_cursor = get_cursor(links)
```

However, I'm struggling to navigate backwards. The official procedure in GAE is to [reverse the cursor and to use a reversed query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors). This makes use of a [reversed()](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py?r=229#1403) function that is part of the Cursor class, which I'm unsure I can access in Django.

But how do I reverse a cursor in djangoappengie?

In case it is not possible I believe that the alternative is to store the cursors client side, pass them via ajax, and then generate a query based on page number. I would prefer to follow the official procedures as much as possible, though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the policy on answering your own question is...
After [further research](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/1CvBVBZOlTg) I found a function that reverses a cursor, namely:

```
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_query
def reverse_cursor(cursor):
    return datastore_query.Cursor.from_websafe_string(cursor).reversed().to_websafe_string()
```

I'll store this in my utils.py and getting a reversed cursor should be simple.

Comment: @doru Thanks, I'll accept my answer as soon as I'm able to. I think that due to my current points (?) I need to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer.